# Different queries depending on optional routes - expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Is it possible to create different queries depending on optional routes?

```
app.get('/:genre/:book?', function (req, res) {

 var genre = req.params.genre;
 var book = req.params.book;

 var sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = ? AND book = ?';

 con.query(sql, [genre, book], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err
  res.send(rows);
 });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "different queries"? What is not working with the code you showed?

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question! The code will fail if the user go to /genre only. The "AND book = ?" is then not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
app.get('/:genre/:book?', function (req, res) {

    var genre = req.params.genre;
    var book = req.params.book;

    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = ?';
    var params = [genre];

    if(book) {
        sql += ' AND book = ?';
        params = [genre, book];
    }

    con.query(sql, params, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.send(rows);
    });

});
```